# Is there a rule of thumb for setting running goals?

Tags: running, tips, goals

I'm pretty new to running and can only run for 2-3 minutes at a time. Is there any rule of thumb I should know of for setting goals? For example, each week run two minutes more or something like that?

I find it really hard to know what I should do, and I think my current method of running till I'm really puffed probably isn't the best way.

Comment: [Adidas MiCoach](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-can-i-use-to-monitor-my-running-workout/32#32) has an option on their website to create a training schedule based on your goal and current level of fitness. These workouts seem very balanced and have similar variations as those in @Chris S's answer. Best of all: it's all free (AFAIK).

Comment: That sounds great too - if you want to put it as an answer, I'll +1 it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is to add no more than 10% (measured in either time or distance) per week. If you're just getting started running, I would recommend the [Couch to 5k](http://c25k.com/) program. I used this last year to start running (after having never done any running in the past), and completed my first marathon in December.

Comment: While I applaud you for managing to to train up to a marathon in such a short time, this doesn't really help him decide how often he should be running and whether to use interval trainings or recovery runs.

Comment: that program looks so nice for a total newbie like me. But what could I do in the case that near home there are only uphills and downhills ? Do you know anything similar?

Comment: @nuc It shouldn't matter too much. The program consists of short intervals of running with walking breaks in between. You'll have a slightly more difficult start but your body should adjust do compensate pretty quickly (unless the hills are really extreme).

Answer (score 6):

Runner's world has a great tool called [Smart Coach](http://www.runnersworld.co.uk/racing/runners-world-smartcoach/3057.html) for improving your speed gradually over time.

The formula is:

- You run 3 days a week
- Day 1 Long run (whatever that means for you)
- Day 2 break
- Day 3 short run
- Day 4 break
- Day 5 speed run or sprints
- Day 6 Break
- Day 7 Break

So if you did the long run on Sundays:

- Sunday: long run
- Monday: break
- Tuesday: short run
- Wednesday: break
- Thursday: sprints
- Friday: break
- Saturday: break

The smart coach is geared towards training for a 5k/10k/marathon competition over a 12 week training period, so you will probably need to reduce the times/distances it gives you quite a bit if you're only running 2-3 minutes. Increasing by one minute or two minutes a week would be more achievable.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm pretty new to running and can only
>   run for 2-3 minutes at a time.

I was in your situation. During a martial arts belt test, they sent us out for a couple-mile run, and I wound up having to walk most of it. Since I knew it would only get worse at higher belts, I decided I needed to become a passable runner.

So here's generally how I did it, using a battery-powered kitchen timer, and running three days a week with a recovery day in between. I focused solely on time, not distance, and would do each step either for a week (three running sessions), or move on faster if I felt comfortable but not like I was pushing myself into injury.

1. 15 minutes, alternating run one minute, walk two (1/2).
2. 15 minutes, alternating run one minute, walk one (1/1).
3. 15 minutes, 2/1.
4. Stick to 15 minutes, but progressively lengthen the cycles (3/1, 4/1, etc.) until you're at run seven, walk 1, run seven.
5. Run 15 minutes straight. By this point, it will probably be a breeze.
6. Increase the time by 2-3 minutes until you get to 30.

At that point, I was doing about 4 km in 30 minutes, which is really a jog. After than, I stuck to 30 minutes but worked on lengthening my stride, which increased my speed and distance.

Worked great for a chubby old geek in his late 40s whose prior running experience was mostly in high school gym class. :-)

Now I consider myself a runner, and have done it literally around the world while on business trips.