# Any social website for sharing and tracking fitness workouts?

Tags: websites, workout

I track my running on DailyMile. The interface is simple, I can share with Facebook and I get inspired watching the running logs of my friends.

Is there a similar social website for general fitness? (I can add weights workouts to DMile, but it is plain text and I get no graphs or logs for them.) For example, I also want to track my weights and core body workouts. The website interface should be as simple as possible and should have sharing ability to Facebook.

Answer (score 6):

How about [Fitocracy](http://www.fitocracy.com)?  Its a website that seeks to incoporate "Gaming" elements into fitness, by awarding you points for your workouts and tracking your "experience" and level as you gain it, as well as providing "quests" for you to complete.  Its still in beta, but there are ways to get invites.

Answer (score 5):

[Fitango.com](http://www.fitango.com/)

> Fitango is a fitness and goal tracking web site that goes beyond merely logging your progress and offers guides, expert-created plans, easy tracking, and peer-based motivation to keep you moving towards your goals—fitness-related or otherwise. ([lifehacker review](http://lifehacker.com/#!5720489/fitango-offers-easy-goal-planning-peer-motivation-and-progress-analysis))

You can create an account using Facebook, which allows you to share your results with friends. Then you either create your own workout or you get one through their Planstore. There are also other categories to get challenged in, but here's an example from the Fitness & Sports department:

[image]

For this example I picked a marathon plan, you can **invite Motivators**. These are friends, trainers or fellow athletes, that can offer advice, motivation and help you stay on track!

[image]

You have to manually keep track of your workouts, which you can then easily publish to Facebook. You can get an overview of your workouts on your Report tab, which gives you graphs and other info.

[image]

Luckily they also have an app, which means you can update your Actions from your mobile phone, rather than requiring a computer.

[image]

As for any further social activity, there's **the Bubble**.

> The Bubble is a place for all users of an Actionplan to discuss their progress, challenges, and experiences. Using the Bubble is simple. Just write something in the text box and click Post. Remember -- whatever you post in the Bubble is visible to all users of that Actionplan. You can easily attach photos or include links in your Bubble posts by clicking the appropriate icons.

[image]

**Summary**

Fitango has a ton of options and since it's still a beta product, they will probably add a lot of new features in the future. One downside compared to apps like RunKeeper or Endomondo, you have to manually fill in your Actions. But in return, it has a lot more social features and let's you keep track of virtually anything!

Comment: +1 that looks like a great site, and goes way beyond just helping to meet fitness goals.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [ChallengeLoop](http://www.challengeloop.com)? It is both an iPhone app and website that motivates you to achieve your health and fitness goals. You can challenge yourself and your friends on the system and add photos, videos, and comments along the way showing your progress. They have Facebook and Twitter sharing capability (I know that's what you're looking for). Both the app and website are free. A lot of personal trainers use it with their clients to motivate them.

Answer (score 2):

I like [myfitnesspal.com](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/)

It is primarily a calorie tracker, but it also keeps a log of nutrition, exercise, and weight. It is free and has [iphone/android/blackberry](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/mobile) apps.

The food calorie calculations use an excellent database of foods and an adequate database of exercises. The foods have most groceries, popular restaurants, and recipes from popular cookbooks and websites. You can also add your own recipes.

The exercises are used to calculate calories burned. This is based on your exercise and your body weight. The database is fairly complete, but there are some limitations and a lot of assumptions that do not always seem to provide accurate estimates, but this may be inherent to any calculation of calories burned (I have no way of checking their estimates).

There are excellent social networking capabilities. - you can tweet, post on facebook, or build a community within the site. I haven't used these though.

You can download your food and exercise logs. And there are some rudimentary data summaries provided by the site.

Answer (score 1):

[JEFIT](http://www.JEFIT.com) is a site and an Android app, mostly targeted for bodybuilders.

It has a huge databases of exercises, almost all of them have illustrations and explanations about how to perform them ([example](http://www.jefit.com/exercises/exercise-database/?id=26)). You can set your routine with the exercises you're doing, and log your workout each time you're at the gym, using the app. You can then track your progress easily and make sure you're getting stronger.

The "social" part comes to play mostly in the routines database of the site, where anyone can share their routine for others to use.

A video about the app [can be found here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTlfzyaWQy0).

The site and app are free, although there's also a paid version of the app ($5) with a bit more options.

Comment: Please take an example [from the answers on this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/13/8), else I'll convert the answers to comments. Users should be able to judge from your answer whether it's a good product or not.

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: let's [discuss on meta](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/80/should-an-answer-to-a-website-recommendation-request-contain-screenshots-and-a-co)

Comment: Sorry, please convert it to a comment.

Comment: @yellowblood, it is meant as a strong encouragement to edit your question into some awesomeness. I don't **want** to convert your answer

Comment: @yellowblood - I don't think you need to provide the same level of detail as Ivo does in his answers, with screenshots and all, but perhaps you can at least explain **why** you suggest Jefit.

Comment: @Ivo Flipse I understood you before but I didn't think I could find the time to edit the answer :) now I have, so I hope it's fine now.

Comment: I've beet using Jefit for a few sessions now and I love it. It's got some annoying quirks, but once I got used to it it was fun to use.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at LiveStrong (Lance Armstrong's site) @ www.livestrong.com and Body Building at www.bodybuilding.com

Comment: please have a look at this [discussion on meta](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/80/should-an-answer-to-a-website-recommendation-request-contain-screenshots-and-a-co)

Answer (score 0):

[Wodboard](http://www.wodboard.com) was just launched last week. It is geared for benchmark workouts, common to the CrossFit program. The idea is to not track everything, just a couple of benchmark workouts a year. You can scale the benchmarks down, they sometimes have really heavy weights for experienced weight lifters.

Aside from benchmarks like the 300 challenge and Fight Gone Bad, there are also categories for distances and weights.

Answer (score -1):

Try Sense https://appsto.re/in/CF1X7.i It automatically tracks pushups, jumps, planks, squats and situps using sensors on your phone. You can share your workouts on facebook and also see workout feeds of your friends. You can even challenge your friends to workouts. It learns from your data and give you insights about how to improve your workouts.